How to Write/Insert data into Spread sheet cells that is located at Share Point using C# and Epplus?
I have been working with inserting records into spread sheet that is located in Share Point using C# with EpPlus package. I have completed with Share point Authentication, loading the site and get the file path, and reading records from spread sheet as well. However, I am stuck with inserting records into spread sheet. The problem I am facing is that, the code which I have for inserting works and does not throw any error. Upon checking in Share Point I can see that the "Modified" value is updated by "A few seconds ago" immediately after executing logic but I am not able to see that Records in the sheet.

Here is my function that inserts the record.
 string url = "<SP_site_Path>/sample.xlsx";
 SpClient.File dataSheet = M_clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(url);
 M_clientContext.Load(dataSheet);
 M_clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

 using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
 {
     var stream = dataSheet.OpenBinaryStream();
     M_clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
     stream.Value.CopyTo(memoryStream);
     memoryStream.Position = 0;

     ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

     // Read the Excel file using EPPlus
     using (var package = new ExcelPackage(memoryStream))
     {
         var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0]; // Assuming data is in the first worksheet
         int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;


         Console.WriteLine("Before: " + worksheet.GetValue(rowCount, 1));

         int newRow = rowCount + 1;
         worksheet.Cells[newRow, 1].Value = "1234";
         worksheet.Cells[newRow, 2].Value = "ABC";
         worksheet.Cells[newRow, 3].Value = "20.09.2024";

         memoryStream.Position = 0;
         package.SaveAs(memoryStream);
     }  
     memoryStream.Position = 0;
 
     dataSheet.SaveBinary(new FileSaveBinaryInformation() {
         ContentStream = memoryStream
     });
     M_clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
 }

Here, Console.WriteLine("Before: " + worksheet.GetValue(rowCount, 1)); prints the last inserted record's value. Which confirms that the data are inserted however I am not able to see those data in the Spread sheet. Moreover, when I try to open the sheet it threw the following error!

